# Update directive variable from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

New to AngularJS I have a simple directive, service and controller. I loop through a list of items from a database in the controller embedded in the directive to render a checkbox list of items. From a form I am able to update my list of items in the database. I would at the same time like to update my list of displayed items with the newly added item and was hoping to benefit from Angulars two-way binding but I can't figure out how...

My directive:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('menu', function (menuService) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '../templates/menu.html',
    controller: function () {
        var me = this;
        menuService.getMenuItems().then(function(data) {
            me.items = data;
        });
    },
    controllerAs: 'menu'
};
});
```

and corresponding html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in menu.items">
            <div class="col-md-4" ng-if="item.menuItem">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label for="{{item._id}}">
                        <input id="{{item._id}}" type="checkbox" name="menuItems" ng-model="menuItems[$index]" ng-true-value="{{item._id}}">
                        {{item.menuItem}}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My issue is now that if I add a new item using this controller

*EDIT: On my page I have two things. 1: A list of items rendered using the directive above and 2: A simple form with a single input field. I enter a new menuItem and click "Save". That triggers the controller below to be called with the new menuItem. The menuItem is then added to a collection in my database but I would like the list on my page to update with the newly added item. Preferably without having to reload the entire page.*

```
    $scope.insertMenuItem = function () {
    $http.post('/menuItems', $scope.formData)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.items = data;
        });
};
```

then the "me.items" in my directive remains unchanged hence so does my list in my browser.

How do I "tie it all together" so that when I call insertMenuItem then my.items are updated automagically?

This didn't come out as well as I had hoped but I hope you get the meaning...

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you are using `controller as` then you need to update `this.items = data` and not `$scope.items`

Comment: I'm sorry but changing my controller from $scope.items to this.items did not help. I still have to reload my page to see the newly inserted item...

Comment: `add a new item using this controller` can you shed some light on this...

Comment: If the `insertMenuItem()` is in a parent controller (not the controller of the `menu` directive), you have to look for a way to communicate such as move `items` into `$scope` to get a benifit of the scope inheritance or using a two-way scope binding.

Comment: Updated question. Is it a bit clearer now?

Comment: Hmm... apparently just updating the collection I'm looping over in ng-repeat doesn't get the ng-repeat loop run again... should have seen that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at this http://jsbin.com/rozexebi/1/edit, it shows how to bind a list of items in a directive to a controller, hope it helps.